# Expectation of joint life span

Tags: probability

The life span of a particular mechanical part is a random variable described by the following PDF:
[image]

### If three such parts are put into service independently at t=0, determine a simle expression for the expected value of the time until the majority of the parts will have failed.

I can get the PDF:
$$
f_L(l) = 0.4 (0 \leq l \leq 2) \\
f_L(l) = -0.4l + 1.2 (2 < l \leq 3)
$$
and the expectation:
$$
E(l) = \int_0^3 l f_L(l) dl \approx 1.27
$$

I think 'majority' means 2 or more, so we can focus on two parts of the three, and pay no attention to the third. The translation is $E(max(l1, l2))$, how will this be derived I currently have no idea.

---

Sorry about the misleading remark "$E(max(l_1, l_2))$", it's wrong to neglect the third part, because if that one fails early, then we only need one of the rest to fail.

Comment: What are you thoughts?

Comment: Your question asks for the first time when 2 out of 3 components fail. You accepted an answer which studies the first time when 2 out of 2 components fail. This is quite different.

Comment: I agree with did.  The accepted answer computes the first time when 2 out of 2 components fail.

Comment: CravingSpirit: Sorry but I am afraid that you lost me: you accepted an answer THEN offered a bounty, without unaccepting the answer nor commenting on the other answer? Could you keep me posted on the status of this question and the answers you received?

Comment: @did, sorry, I've been busy with other things. I will check both answers and give the bounty to the preferred one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ denote the life span of any given component and $T$ the first time when at least 2 out of 3 components fail. The event $[T\gt t]$ means either that none of the 3 components fails before time $t$ or that exactly 1 component out of 3 fails before that time, hence, for every $t\gt0$,
$$
\mathbb P(T\gt t)=\mathbb P(X\gt t)^3+3\mathbb P(X\gt t)^2\mathbb P(X\lt t),
$$
that is,
$$
\mathbb P(T\gt t)=1-3u(t)^2+2u(t)^3=v(t)^2(3-2v(t)),
$$
with
$$
u(t)=\mathbb P(X\lt t),\qquad v(t)=1-u(t)=\mathbb P(X\gt t).
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\mathbb E(T)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P(T\gt t)\mathrm dt.
$$
In the present case, the density of $X$ is $f_X(t)=\frac25$ if $0\lt t\lt 2$ and $f_X(3-t)=\frac25t$ if $0\lt t\lt 1$. Hence
$u(t)=\frac25t$ if $0\lt t\lt 2$ and $v(3-t)=\frac15t^2$ if $0\lt t\lt 1$. This yields
$$
\mathbb E(T)=\int_0^2(1-3u(t)^2+2u(t)^3)\mathrm dt+\int_0^1v(3-t)^2(3-2v(3-t))\mathrm dt,
$$
that is,
$$
\mathbb E(T)=\int_0^2(1-\tfrac{12}{25}t^2+\tfrac{16}{125}t^3)\mathrm dt+\int_0^1\tfrac1{25}t^4(3-\tfrac25t^2)\mathrm dt,
$$
or,
$$
\mathbb E(T)=\left[t-\tfrac{4}{25}t^3+\tfrac{4}{125}t^4\right]_{t=0}^{t=2}+\left[\tfrac3{125}t^5-\tfrac2{125}\tfrac17t^7\right]_{t=0}^{t=1},
$$
that is,
$$
\mathbb E(T)=2-\tfrac{32}{25}+\tfrac{64}{125}+\tfrac3{125}-\tfrac2{125\cdot7}=\tfrac{1097}{875}=1.253\overline{714285}.
$$

Comment: +1, although I think you should have $\frac{16}{125}t^3$ rather than $\frac{16}{25}t^3$ in the first integral in the third-to-last displayed line, as well as $2$ instead of $1$ right after the = sign in the last line.  That changes the final value of $E(T)$ as well.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Thanks a lot for the checking. I hope the numerics are correct now.

Comment: Your new final number for $E(T)$ agrees with what I have.

Comment: @did, could you please explain this a bit more: $$
\mathbb E(T)=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P(T\gt t)\mathrm dt.
$$

Comment: Yes: write $P(T\gt t)$ as an integral on $(t,+\infty)$ and use Tonelli to exchange the order of the two integration signs.

Comment: @did I still cannot see the connection between $\mathbb E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf_X (x) dx$ and the formula above, could you please give a thorough explanation? Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Sorry but I think I already did (did you try to follow the hint I gave?). See [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition).

Comment: @did Okay, thanks for the link. It seems to involved some advanced calculus, I need to brush that up.

Answer (score 1):

The value for $E \left[ \max \left( L_1, L_2 \right) \right]$ is computed in
the following way. First, the distribution of the maximum of two identically
independently distribued random variable $L_1$ and $L_2$ is given by $2 f
\left( \ell \right) F \left( \ell \right)$ where $f \left( \ell \right)$ is
the density and $F \left( \ell \right)$ is the cumulative distribution
function. This is well known, you could find the formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution). It is not
difficult to derive:
\begin{eqnarray*} 
  \Pr \left[ \max \left( L_1, L_2 \right) \leqslant \ell \right] & = & \Pr
  \left[ \left\{ L_1 \leqslant \ell \right\} \cap \left\{ L_2 \leqslant \ell
  \right\} \right]\\
  & = & \Pr \left[ L_1 \leqslant \ell \right] \Pr \left[ L_2 \leqslant \ell
  \right]\\
  & = & F \left( \ell \right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
Taking derivative gives the density $2 f \left( \ell \right) F \left( \ell
\right)$.

The probability density function $f(\ell)$ is given by (as you indicated)
$$ f \left( \ell \right) = \frac{2}{5} 1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2 \right) + \left(
   - \frac{2}{5} \ell + \frac{6}{5} \right) 1_{\ell} \left[ 2, 3 \right) $$
where the notation $1_{\ell}A$ with interval $A$ is that of an indicator variable. This means
$$ 1_{\ell} \left( A \right) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lll}
     1 &  & \text{if } \ell \in A\\
     0 &  & \text{otherwise}
   \end{array} \right. $$
Therefore the cumlative distribution function is given by
$$ F( \ell)= \frac{2 \ell}{5} 1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2
   \right) + \frac{1}{5} \left( - \ell^2 + 6 \ell - 4 \right) 1_{\ell} \left[
   2, 3 \right) + 1_{\ell} \left[ 3, \infty \right) $$
Multiplying both we get the density
\begin{eqnarray*}
  2 f \left( \ell \right) F \left( \ell \right) & = & 2 \left\{ \frac{2}{5}
  1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2 \right) + \left( - \frac{2}{5} \ell + \frac{6}{5}
  \right) 1_{\ell} \left[ 2, 3 \right) \right\}\\
  & \times & \left\{ \frac{2 \ell}{5} 1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2 \right) +
  \frac{1}{5} \left( - \ell^2 + 6 \ell - 4 \right) 1_{\ell} \left[ 2, 3
  \right) + 1_{\ell} \left[ 3, \infty \right) \right\}\\
  & = & \frac{8 \ell}{25} 1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2 \right) + \frac{4}{25} \left(
  - \ell + 3 \right) \left( - \ell^2 + 6 \ell - 4 \right) 1_{\ell} \left[ 2, 3
  \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
and therefore
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left[ \max \left( L_1, L_2 \right) \right] & = & \frac{8}{25} \int_0^2
  \ell^2 \mathrm{d} \ell + \frac{4}{25} \int_2^3 \ell \left( - \ell + 3
  \right) \left( - \ell^2 + 6 \ell - 4 \right) \mathrm{d} \ell\\
  & = & \frac{637}{375}\\ 
 & \approx & 1.69867
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure though the CDF $F( \ell)= \frac{2 \ell}{5} 1_{\ell} \left[ 0, 2
   \right) + \frac{1}{5} \left( - \ell^2 + 6 \ell - 4 \right) 1_{\ell} \left[
   2, 3 \right) + 1_{\ell} \left[ 3, \infty \right)$ is correct though, could you please check it?

Comment: @CravingSpirit It looks fine to me because the CDF is increasing between 0 and 1 on the support and $2fF$ is a density since it integrates to one. Where do you see an error?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: The question asks for the first time when 2 out of 3 components fail. Your answer studies the first time when 2 out of 2 components fail. This is quite different.